# Python 3.X trouble having to iterate through a list, calling function within another, Justifying width

Tags: python, python-3.x, iteration, nested-lists, calling-convention

With this python assignment, I am trying to get the end result of producing a star for a movie rating. I am having difficulties because even with one to one help, I cannot decipher how to return the list seen below in the instructions.

**instructions**

*"Write a function called count_ratings that will take a list of asterisks that represent
an individuals rating for a given app and return a list of the number of 5 stars, 4 stars,
3 stars, 2 stars, and 1 star ratings.
For example, if you called this function and passed it the list ["*", "***", "****", "***","*****", "****", "**"] it would return the list [1, 1, 2, 2, 1] (where this means there are (1) 1-star rating, (1) 2-star rating, (2) 3-star rating, (2) 4-star ratings and (1) 5-star rating.)"*

**At which I did that correctly, or at least I thought But as I went on to the further instructions.**

**1. Write a function called print_ratings that takes no parameters. This function will:**

◦ Use the code at the end of the section to create a ratings variable that
represents the list of ratings that you are going to use to in this program.

#### ratings = ["*****", "*", "**", "**", "*", "***", "*****", "****", "****","*",

#### "*", "*", "*", "***", "*****", "*****", "*****", "*****", "*****"]

• Call the count_ratings function passing it the list of ratings.
• Take the list that count_ratings returns and iterate through it and print out the rating

breakdown based on what the count_ratings function returns. Suppose
count_ratings returns the following list [4, 2, 4, 2, 6], you want to print a histogram
of this count. See the example output below.

1. Call print_ratings from main .
2. Run your code to verify that it works correctly.

**At which I had done correctly, but..** as I tried calling the variable the error was stated as **'name 'count_list' is not defined' This is the end result of the output**

5 Stars:
|# # # # # # #                    |

4 Stars:
|# #                              |

3 Stars:
|# # # #                          |

2 Stars:
|# #                              |

1 Stars:
|# # # #                          |

***The list must be printed in descending order, labeled as shown above.***

• Each ' # ' represents one rating of X number of stars. So in the example provided,there are six entries with 5 stars, two entries with 4-stars and etc.

• Each visual representation of the count must be left justified, with a total width of 25.
Place the pipe symbol to the left and right of the printed line

**Here is where I got to, any help is needed, because I cannot find the solution after switching out variables and parameters I also need help because justifying the code seems to boggle me.**

```
def count_ratings(st):
   count_list = [0,0,0,0,0]
   for i in st:
   if st == "*":
         count_list[0] = count_list[0] + 1

   elif st == "**":
         count_list[1] = count_list[1] + 1
   elif st == "***":
         count_list[2] = count_list[2] + 1

   elif st == "****":
         count_list[3] = count_list[3] + 1  
   else:
        if st == "*****":
         count_list[4] = count_list[4] + 1
   return count_list
def print_ratings():
   ratings = ["*****", "***", "**", "*****", "****", "**", "*", "***","**","*","**","*","*****","****","*****"]
   count_ratings(ratings)
   for i in count_list:
     print (count_list)
def main(): # defining the main
   process_user_word() # calling the process user word
   print_ratings()
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Three bugs with your code:

1. `count_list` is not defined in `print_ratings()` because you're using it within the scope of a different function, `count_ratings()` One approach to fixing this can be to bring the count_list into `print_ratings()`, and then passing it as an argument into `count_ratings()`.
2. When you use a for-each loop in python, ex. `for i in st`, `i` is the individual element, and `st` is the array. So in `count_ratings()`, all your if-clauses should use `i` instead of `st`.
3. `process_user_word()` is not defined. Not sure if you didn't provide it on purpose or not.

Here's the working code:

```
def count_ratings(st, count_list):
   for i in st:
      if i == "*":
         count_list[0] = count_list[0] + 1
      elif i == "**":
         count_list[1] = count_list[1] + 1
      elif i == "***":
         count_list[2] = count_list[2] + 1
      elif i == "****":
         count_list[3] = count_list[3] + 1  
      else:
         if i == "*****":
            count_list[4] = count_list[4] + 1

   return count_list

def print_ratings():
   ratings = ["*****", "***", "**", "*****", "****", "**", "*", "***","**","*","**","*","*****","****","*****"]
   count_list = [0,0,0,0,0]
   count_list = count_ratings(ratings, count_list)

   for i in count_list:
     print(count_list)

def main(): # defining the main
   print_ratings()

main()
```